# Is it possible to add the current time to each STEP in Allure reports?

Tags: testing, automation, report, allure

Is it possible to add the current time to each STEP in Allure reports?

I am writing Automation using Java and TestNG.
I was trying to search for an option to add the current time to each step, but could not find how to add it to the annotation without adding it as a parameter.

At the moment my Allure report looks like this:

- Navigate to page       200ms
- Click on Open button   250ms
  ....

I would like it to look something like this:

- 15:00:00   Navigate to page       200ms
- 15:00:01   Click on Open button   250ms

Thanks

Comment: Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: I would love to see this in Allure.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very late response to this question. Here is my solution.

Add the following lines of code

```
 @Step("{0}")
    public void log(final String message){
        //intentionally empty
    }

    public void mylogger(String msg){
        Date d = new Date();
        String[] dateTokens = d.toString().split(" ");
        System.out.println(dateTokens[3] + " " + msg);
        log(dateTokens[3] + msg);
    }
```

When you want to log something call the following function:

```
mylogger("This is my log");
```